# JAVA - Problems initializing individual elements of an array

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

I'm very new to programming and I must be missing something here.  The first section works.  The second section blows up with an error.  Why is that?

```
// this works
private static int[] test2 = {1,2,3};

// this is ok
private static int[] test1 = new int[3];
// these three lines do not work
// tooltip states ... "cannot find symbol.  class test1. ']' expected."
test1[0] = 1;
test1[1] = 2;
test1[2] = 3;
```

Comment: this should work, you might want to post full code

Comment: can you please post your whole java file? it's hard to work out the scope of what you've pasted based on your current question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you've posted, the lines

```
test1[0] = 1;
test1[1] = 2;
test1[2] = 3;
```

need to be inside a method or constructor. Looks like you have them outside at the class level. Lets say `MyClass` is the name of your class. Add a constructor and put the three statements inside it:

```
MyClass {
    test1[0] = 1;
    test1[1] = 2;
    test1[2] = 3;
}
```

**Edit:** You can only declare variables directly inside the class. A declaration statement can, however, *also include initialization* (on the same line):

```
int[] arrayA; // declare an array of integers
int[] arrayB = new int[5]; // declare and create an array of integers
int[] arrayC = {1, 2, 3}; // declare, create and initialize an array of integers
```

The following, on the other hand, is not a declaration and involves only initialization:

```
arrayB[0] = 1;
```

and so it can't go directly under the class. It must be enclosed within a method, constructor or initialization block.

**See Also:**

[Arrays Java tutorial at Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: Good guess. I haven't thought he might actually put initialization right after definition.

Comment: That's what I did - had them at the class level vs. in the constructor.  I guess I was just wondering why the first way of initialization (int[] var = {x,y,z}) works at the class level and the other way doesn't.  Mind boggling.

Answer (score 2):

To work your java source file must be something like this:

```
public class Test
{
    // this works
    private static int[] test2 = {1,2,3};

    // this is ok
    private static int[] test1 = new int[3];

    public static void main( String args[] ){

        test1[0] = 1;
        test1[1] = 2;
        test1[2] = 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also put the code in a static initialization block which is executed when the class is loaded.

```
public class Test {
   // this works
   private static int[] test2 = {1,2,3};

   // this is ok
   private static int[] test1 = new int[3];

   static {
       test1[0] = 1;
       test1[1] = 2;
       test1[2] = 3;
   }
}
```